# find and copy file with yesterdays date to file with out date

Tags: copy

```
I am trying to write a linux script that will go up to my server.  find a file with yesterdays date in the name and copy it with out the date.
File = folder/folder2/mypicture20230419.jpg
```

I need it to copy over as: folder/folder2/mypicture.jpg
mypicture.jpg may already exist, it can overwrite the existing file.
I new to linux and this has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `date` utility to get the yesterday's date. Then, use it to find the matching file(s), and copy them. Use the `${variable/search/replacement}` form to delete the date:

```
yesterday=$(date --date yesterday +"%Y%m%d")
folder=folder/folder2
for oldfile in "$folder"/*"$yesterday"*
do
    newfile="${oldfile/"$yesterday"/}"
    cp "$oldfile" "$newfile"
done
```